# Add every new file to svn, except those that are ignored

Tags: svn, configuration

I'm new to subversion. I've created a repository, and I want to make the first commit.

There are some files and folders that should not be checked in, such as `cache/` or `log/`. I've used `svn propset svn:ignore -F svn_ignore.txt`.

I want to have a simple way to add new files to svn. Is there a way to do this while respecting the svn:ignore setting ? The following commands add every file, even the ignored ones :

```
svn add --force .

alias svn_add_all='svn st|grep ^?|sed s/?//|xargs svn add $1'
```

**EDIT** Here's what I get :

```
$ svn status
?       web/images/test/film_super8.jpg
?       web/images/test/ea_dl_manager.jpg
?       web/images/test/minecraft_anaglyph.png
$ svn propget svn:ignore
cache/*
log/*
web/images/blog/*
web/images/test/*
```

Comment: which operating systems do you use , You can use the svn clients available for different OS

They make it much easier to organize

Comment: for the moment I added everything then I removed the files I don't want with "svn delete --keep-local the_file"

Comment: You can use rapid svn on ubuntu system, its pretty decent tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The patterns are strictly for that directory—they do not carry
>   recursively into subdirectories.

See [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html)

So you must apply your patterns on all the directories, or only on the directories where that ignore is necessary.

So the pattern shouldn't include directories like you do. `web/images/blog/*` won't work.
You should go to the `blog` folder and set `svn:ignore` to `*`

Some clients have a "Apply recursively" feature that does that for you. I don't know if you can do that with the "default" client.
But in your case, it would be useless. It may be used when a specific file or pattern must be ignored everywhere (like `*.suo` files for Visual Studio projects)

Answer (score 2):

`svn status` should not display an ignored file.
But the issue might be in the way you do ignore a file: see "[Command Line svn:ignore a file](http://blog.bogojoker.com/2008/07/command-line-svnignore-a-file/)"

> You don’t `svn:ignore` a file.
>
> You put an `svn:ignore` property **on the directory** to ignore that filename pattern!

```
# Add just the single file to the current directories ignore list (like above)
# Note the dot at the end of the command is important
svn propset svn:ignore secret.txt .

# See that things worked
svn propget svn:ignore .    # Notice the single file was added to the list
svn status --no-ignore      # You should see an 'I' next to the ignored files
```

Comment: I did `svn propset svn:ignore -F svn_ignore.txt .`, but they still show up in `status`

Comment: @Manu: "they"? but `svn propset svn:ignore -F svn_ignore.txt .` would be only for *one* file (and only in the current directory): `./svn_ignore.txt`

Comment: `-F` can be used to ignore the file patterns defined in the file

Comment: @Manu: right, so the patterns defined in that `secret.txt` file aren't somehow applied, then?

Comment: @Manu: so the "ignore" property has been registered, but its pattern in it is not quite right, as the `svn status` doesn't take it into account. Could you test with one simple pattern? Or test with just one file? The main issue is to have an `svn status` *not* displaying any ignored files.